# How to Jumble Up Outputted Characters in C?

Tags: c

Say for instance my output is: thwhglHDGQYE836

IS there a way of jumbling it up as output? if there is a way, some advice would be nice thanks :).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char c;

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Your Random Password is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        c = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        c = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        c = '1' + rand() % ('1' - '9' + 1);
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean your `input` is `thwhglHDGQYE836`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "jumbling up"? What's wrong with the current output?

Comment: Do you mean you want to shuffle the output so that it's not in strict lowercase-uppercase-number order?  If so, well, use a shuffle algorithm.

Comment: Do you want your program to give the output `thwhglHDGQYE836` ?

Comment: Sorry, but yes I mean I want to shuffle up the output so it would appear as the upper, lower and numbers jumbled together

Comment: Randomly generates the output like kswuagJHDWYU816 but i want it to appear as 5XhPh2kWsy6ALQw

Comment: I think what you want to is to encrypt your password. Google cipher, for instance.

Comment: Is there a code to use to shuffle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    char password[6 + 6 + 3 + 1];
    int i, j=0, len=sizeof(password)-1;

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Your Random Password is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        password[j++] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        password[j++] = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        password[j++] = '1' + rand() % ('1' - '9' + 1);
    password[j] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(password)-1; ++i)
        {
        char c = password[i];
        j = rand() % len;
        password[i] = password[j];
        password[j] = c;
        }
    printf("%s\n\n", password);
    system("pause");
}
```